# How to get the URL of the frame in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, url, iframe, frame

I want to check my URL is correct redirected (parameter etc.) in Chrome. In the address bar only the main URL is listed. In IE all you need is right-click -> Properties. How to obtain the same in Chrome?
The URL in the source of the e.g. iframe tag doesn't solve the problem, because the page in frame makes redirects, postbacks etc without changing the source in the iframe. So you can't find the URL in the html source.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Right-clicking on the frame should show you the option "View frame source". By clicking on it, it will open the source code in a new tab. Its URL is on the address bar. Just have to ignore to remove the "view-source:" prefix, though.

Answer (score 4):

Try using "Inspect Element" over desired frame. You will see original frameset HTML code and selected page code nested.

Comment: Unfortunately you can see only the htmml code, but not the request url like in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Shurup In Chrome 20.x, once you're in *Developer Tools* (via *Inspect Element*) you can click the *Resources* tab, and it will display a *Frames* tree. If you open up the frames, you can right-click on the resource inside, which will allow you to *Open link in new tab* or *Copy link address*

Comment: **Beware**, the parent frame's html doesn't change to reflect navigation within the child frame.

Answer (score 0):

go to the system menu (wrench/spanner) Tools -> Developer tools.

you should be able to see the frame url in there

Comment: no, it shows only the source code of the parent page, I see only the initial url of the frame. After redirect it doesn't shows the updated url.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a "frame" is more a "popup" and has NO URL, because it is compiled together from different code parts from the main .html page. There is NO URL for the "frame"

Main: http://www.celine-cellier.com/fr/produits/boites-a-bijoux

If you click on one of the displayed cases, then there is a "frame" coming up, which explains the case in detail (French). The "frame" has no URL, because all the code (Joomla) is hidden in the main .html

In the main .html are the images downloaded, AND the content text is taken from the main .html also, and so on. The only difference is the # sign at the end of the original main URL

Frame: http://www.celine-cellier.com/fr/produits/boites-a-bijoux#

The frame itself does NOT have an own URL, so it can NOT be found!